# Print out a output that is different each time in a tuple via a user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a piece of code that asks a person to input the hours worked for 6 different workers, each time asking them to import the hours worked. It then asks for the amount of pay per hour.

It should then print out the gross pay for each worker. However it only prints out the last input that has been entered so whatever input for worker 6 gets times and then printed 6 times.

Is there anyway to do this and have the number change each time and print the correct amount for each worker without the need to print out 6 different outcomes with a var each?

Here is the code

```
my_list = [
    ("employee 1"),
    ("employee 2"),
    ("employee 3"),
    ("employee 4"),
    ("employee 5"),
    ("employee 6"),
]
my_list_money = []


for (employee) in my_list:
    user = int(input("Enter the hours worked by {}.".format(employee)))
    
user_ = int(input("Enter the hourly pay rate: "))
total = (user * user_)


for (employee) in my_list:
    print("Gross pay for {}.".format(employee),total)
```

and this is my output :

```
Enter the hours worked by employee 1.7
Enter the hours worked by employee 2.8
Enter the hours worked by employee 3.7
Enter the hours worked by employee 4.6
Enter the hours worked by employee 5.6
Enter the hours worked by employee 6.9
Enter the hourly pay rate: 8
Gross pay for employee 1. 72
Gross pay for employee 2. 72
Gross pay for employee 3. 72
Gross pay for employee 4. 72
Gross pay for employee 5. 72
Gross pay for employee 6. 72
```

Comment: Indent `user_ = ...` and `total = ...` so that they are ***in*** the loop; after `total =` append  `(employee,total)` to a separate list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined a `my_money_list`, but you never used it.

Here is how:

```
my_list = [
    ("employee 1"),
    ("employee 2"),
    ("employee 3"),
    ("employee 4"),
    ("employee 5"),
    ("employee 6"),
]

my_list_money = []

for (employee) in my_list:
    user = int(input(f"Enter the hours worked by {employee}. "))
    my_list_money.append(user)
    
user_ = int(input("Enter the hourly pay rate: "))

for employee, user in zip(my_list, my_list_money):
    total = user * user_
    print(f"Gross pay for {employee}: {total}")
```

You can even do this with [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
my_list = [
    ("employee 1"),
    ("employee 2"),
    ("employee 3"),
    ("employee 4"),
    ("employee 5"),
    ("employee 6"),
]

my_list_money = [int(input(f"Enter the hours worked by {employee}. ")) for employee in my_list]
user_ = int(input("Enter the hourly pay rate: "))

print('\n'.join([f"Gross pay for {employee}: {user * user_}" for employee, user in zip(my_list, my_list_money)]))
```

---

Input:

```
Enter the hours worked by employee 1. 5
Enter the hours worked by employee 2. 2
Enter the hours worked by employee 3. 6
Enter the hours worked by employee 4. 3
Enter the hours worked by employee 5. 1
Enter the hours worked by employee 6. 3
```

Output:

```
Enter the hourly pay rate: 23
Gross pay for employee 1: 115
Gross pay for employee 2: 46
Gross pay for employee 3: 138
Gross pay for employee 4: 69
Gross pay for employee 5: 23
Gross pay for employee 6: 69
```